# faking AJAX call with fadeToggle() spinner

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein, fadeout

I am calling an ajax function(**checkConnection**) and because i want a return value i've set the **async** option to **false** . 
Then i also call the **notificationConfirm** with **async : false** in order to wait for the function to complete and then update the notifications with **getNotifications**. Because this process takes some time and i need to inform the user to "wait" I'm fading in the spinner and after i fade it out. But it doesn't work. Can please someone explain me why because I'm new at jQuery or propose me a way to visualize the ajax-call? I have to mention that without those two function calls the fadeIn-fadeOut effect works. thank you in advance

```
 $(document).on('click','.wrapper',function(e){

                if ($(e.target).is('#check-notification')){
                    return;
                }
                else if ($(e.target).is('.send-email')){
                    $(this).find('#spinner').fadeIn('fast');
                    var con = checkConnection("<?php echo site_url('ajax/checkConnection')?>");
                    if (con == "yes"){
                    var url = '<?php echo site_url("ajax/sendMail"); ?>';
                    notificationConfirm($(e.target),url);
                    $(this).find('#spinner').fadeOut('fast');
                    $(document).trigger('getNotifications');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('No connection');
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if ($('.notifications').is(":visible"))
                        $('.notifications').hide('slow');
                }
        });
```

the first function:

```
checkConnection = function(url) {
        var res = $.ajax(url,{
            datatype: 'html',
            async: false
        });
        return res.responseText;
    };
```

the second function:

```
notificationConfirm = function(element, url) {
        var data = {
            "subject": element.parent('.notification-item').find('.notification-subject').text(),
            "profID": element.parent('.notification-item').find('.hidden-prof').text(),
            "date": element.parent('.notification-item').find('.notification-date').text(),
            "code": element.parents('div').attr('id')
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'html',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            async : false,
            error: function() {
                alert('// error message //');
            },
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Show rest of your code or provide jsfiddle.net

Comment: Setting async false just because you want to return a value is never a good reason. Unfortunately, cannot help you more, not enough relevant code provided

Comment: quotes are not correct `'<?php echo site_url("ajax/sendMail"); ?>';`

Comment: actually those quotes won't raise any errors since the code inside php tags will output url without qutoes.

Comment: added relevant code to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to show and hide ajax loader is using beforeSend and success callbacks. you can use `async:true`. also if you need to execute a code once an ajax request is finished, use the block inside success callback. that is the main reason for that callback. so you don't have to use `async:false` for your ajax calls. 
example:

```
$(document).on('click','.wrapper',function(e){

            if ($(e.target).is('#check-notification')){
                return;
            }
            else if ($(e.target).is('.send-email')){
                $(this).find('#spinner').fadeIn('fast');
                checkConnection("<?php echo site_url('ajax/checkConnection')?>");
            }
            else{
                if ($('.notifications').is(":visible"))
                    $('.notifications').hide('slow');
            }
    });

checkConnection = function(url) {
        var res = $.ajax(url,{
            datatype: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
              $("#loading-image").show();
           },
           success: function(msg) {
              $("#loading-image").hide();
              if (msg == "yes"){
                var url = '<?php echo site_url("ajax/sendMail"); ?>';
                notificationConfirm($(e.target),url);
                $(this).find('#spinner').fadeOut('fast');
                $(document).trigger('getNotifications');
              }
              else {
                    alert('No connection');
              }
           }
        });
    };
```